# SQL query error with variables

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm currently having a problem with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO likes (idUsuario, idTweet)
                                    SELECT {$_SESSION['idUsuario']}, {$id} FROM  tweet
                                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT idTweet FROM tweet WHERE idTweet={$id}) 
                                    AND NOT EXISTS(
                                        SELECT idTweet FROM likes
                                        WHERE idUsuario ={$_SESSION['idUsuario']} AND idTweet = {$id})
                                        LIMIT 1
```

When checking in SQL tab at myphpadmin i keep getting errors pointed at the chars such as "$,["

And at the botton it says that I have a syntax error near

```
'['idUsuario']}, {$id} FROM  tweet
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT idTweet FROM tw'
```

I'm not sure what the error is here. Any help would be nice!

edit: I apologize, this is the full code. Basically, I'm making a tweeter like page. In here i show the tweets of the people i follow and i have a like button (which is where i'm having trouble with the query since it's not inserting anything in my data base):

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('db.php');
$idUser = $_SESSION['idUsuario'];

$mensaje = "";

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $tweet = $_POST['tweet'];

                if($_POST['tweet'] != ""){
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `tweet`(`idUsuario`, `tweet`) VALUES (".$idUser.",'".$tweet."')";
                    consulta($query);
                }
            }

                error_reporting(0);
                $usuariolog = $_GET['idUsuario'];


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/inicio.css">
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="perfilUsuario.php" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" placeholder="Perfil">
    <?php 
        $usuariolog = $idUser;
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="idUsuario" value=<?php echo "$idUser" ?>>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea style="resize:none" id="caja" name="tweet" placeholder="Twittea!"></textarea>
    <div>
    <input id="boton" type="submit" name="enviar" value="tuit">
    </div>
</form>



    <?php 
                $usuarioSeguido = 'select z.idUsuarioSeguido from follow z where z.idUsuarioSigue = '.$_SESSION['idUsuario'];
                $resUsuario = consulta($usuarioSeguido); 
                $sUser = ''; 
                while($resQ = mysqli_fetch_array($resUsuario)){
                    $sUser .= $resQ['idUsuarioSeguido'].',';

                }
                $sUser = substr($sUser, 0, strlen($sUser) -1);
                //$sUser .= $_SESSION['idUsuario']; 

                $tweets = 'select * from usuario a, tweet b 
                            where a.idUsuario = b.idUsuario 
                            AND b.idUsuario in ('.$sUser.') and a.estatus = 1 and b.estatus = 1
                            order by b.fecha desc, b.idTweet desc; '; 

                $resTweet = consulta($tweets); 
            ?>

            <form action="carga_imagen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            </form>

            <div id="bodyApp">
                <table style="width: 50%; ">

                    <?php 
                            while($tweet = mysqli_fetch_array($resTweet)){
                        ?>
                            <tr style="border:#DEEDED solid 1px; ">
                                <td style="width:10%">
                                    <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="" style="width:20px;">
                                </td>
                                <td style="width:89%; ">
                                    <p>
                                        <?php echo $tweet['tweet']?>
                                    </p>
                                    <small>
                                        <?php echo $tweet['userName']?>
                                    </small>
                                    <small>
                                        <?php echo $tweet['fecha']?><br><br>
                                        <a href="inicio.php?type=tweet%id=<?php echo $tweet['idTweet'];?>">Like! </a><br>
                                    </small>
                                </td>


                            </tr>


                    <?php 
                            }

                            $query = "
                            SELECT tweet.idTweet, tweet.tweet
                            FROM 
                            tweet

                            ";
                            $rQ = consulta($query);

                            if(isset($_GET['type'], $_GET['id']))
                            {
                                $type = $_GET['type'];
                                $id = $_GET['id'];
                            }
                            if($type == "tweet"){
                                $QU = "
                                    INSERT INTO likes (idUsuario, idTweet)
                                    SELECT {$_SESSION['idUsuario']}, {$id} FROM  tweet
                                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT idTweet FROM tweet WHERE idTweet={$id}) 
                                    AND NOT EXISTS(
                                        SELECT idTweet FROM likes
                                        WHERE idUsuario ={$_SESSION['idUsuario']} AND idTweet = {$id})
                                        LIMIT 1

                                ";
                                consulta($QU);
                                print_r($);
                                header("location:inicio.php");
                            }
                    ?>

                </table>
            </div>  
        </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your actuall code in your question. It could be that you're sending your query is plain text but we can't be sure of that without seeing your code.

Comment: `$_SESSION['idUsuario']` is not a SQL command - that is PHP. Therefore it won't work on phpMyAdmin (which is a GUI for interacting with your mysql database)